# How to Create Local WikiText Variable in MediaWiki Template?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

How to create a temporary local variable using wikitext, in a MediaWiki template?

Example:

```
MyVar = "Banana"

{{#if: {{{2}}}
|<small>MyVar</small>
|'''MyVar'''
}}
```

[This extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables) ought to do the trick, but wondering if there's a native method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MediaWiki's [documentation on the matter](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Variables), there are built-in variables in MediaWiki, such as `{{CURRENTYEAR}}`, and extensions like [Variables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Extension:Variables) that can create custom variables. However, there is no native way to define variables.

Answer (score 1):

As the arachnoid said: you can't do that natively. Either you create your own extension (which is not feasible in most cases) or you use helper templates. By this, you can pass data as parameters, and in the inner template, you can reuse that data multiple times. Which is your intention, I think.

By the way: {{#if: {{{2}}}|...|...}} doesn't work. You need to write {{{2|}}}, or you will get `{{{2}}}` literally if no second parameter is passed.

Let's say you have a template Foo. Then you can create a helper templates Foo/X, and use it in Foo like this:

```
{{Foo/X | Banana | small={{{2|}}} }}
```

I put some spaces between the braces, in practice, they might be disruptive.

In Foo/X, you write:

```
{{#if:{{{small|}}}|<small>{{{1|}}}</small>|'''{{{1|}}}'''}}
```

Yes, it's bothersome. But without variables, you must resort to parameters. Using the Variables extension is something you should refrain from, since it has become deprecated. Mediawiki plans to create a parallelized parser, and in such an environment, Variables just don't work any more.

Comment: i developed a solution. It's a couple years since i worked on it, so i don't remember the details. It's explained here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TopicTags